# Elasticsearch - Search fails after upgrading to 2.1.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, elasticsearch, wildfly

I am working on a Java EE 7 WebApplication (running in wildfly 10) using an embedded Elasticsearch.
After **upgrading to elasticsearch 2.1.1** searching is not working anymore. (indexing seems to work)

Dependencies that worked:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Upgraded dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

After indexing a very basic document (indexing seems to work), searching fails with the following exception:

```
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException : all shards failed [Proxied because : Original exception caused: class java.io.NotSerializableException: org.elasticsearch.action.search.ShardSearchFailure]
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:228)
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$1.onFailure(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:174)
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerResponseHandler.handleException(ActionListenerResponseHandler.java:46)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.local.LocalTransport.handleException(LocalTransport.java:354)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.local.LocalTransport.handlerResponseError(LocalTransport.java:345)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.local.LocalTransport.messageReceived(LocalTransport.java:241)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.local.LocalTransportChannel$2.run(LocalTransportChannel.java:99)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.NotSerializableExceptionWrapper: _byteSymbolCanonicalizer
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.smile.SmileFactory._createParser(SmileFactory.java:404)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.smile.SmileFactory.createParser(SmileFactory.java:327)
at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.smile.SmileXContent.createParser(SmileXContent.java:107)
at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.smile.SmileXContent.createParser(SmileXContent.java:113)
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:817)
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:651)
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:617)
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeDfsPhase(SearchService.java:262)
at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchDfsTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:360)
at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchDfsTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:357)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.local.LocalTransport$2.doRun(LocalTransport.java:280)
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is how my search looks like:

```
QueryStringQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(queryString);
SearchResponse searchResponse = this.client.prepareSearch(INDEX_NAME)
            .setTypes(typeName)
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
            .setQuery(qb)
            .setFrom(offset)
            .setSize(limit)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

Comment: The 2.0 branch of ES used Jackson 2.5.3 while the 2.1 branch uses Jackson 2.6.2. Can you verify you don't have a conflicting Jackson library inside your web app?

Comment: I have 2.7.0 of jackson-databind and jackson-annotation. In addition i am using the resteasy-jackson-provider (provided scope) as i am running on wildfly 10.

Comment: Then you might have issues since your embedded ES depends on Jackson 2.6.2 and you have Jackson 2.7.0 bundled within your app. Try to bundle 2.6.2 instead and see if that solves.

Comment: Still not working... Could it be, that resteasy-jackson-provider is interfering ?

Comment: Might be. Which version is it?

Comment: I am using provided-scope in wildfly 10 - think this is jackson2-provider-3.0.14

Comment: Ok, I think that one depends on Jackson 2.7.0, that might explain. Embedding ES is a tricky business because you need to make sure that dependencies don't collide. You might be better off running a standalone ES.

Comment: The weird thing is that the "older" version of ES is working fine within Wildfly 10.

Comment: would you be able to provide some examples, such as what your document looks like and what your query looks like?  Also, is the rest of your cluster also on 2.1.1, or is this a single node?

Comment: The document ist just a simple test (e.g. {id:1, name:"Peter"} ). Search fails even with a Standard-Match-All query. So nothing special except that i am running an embedded node in Wildfly 10. With ES 2.0.2 everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around that problem by shading elasticsearch dependencies

#### 1. I created a separate maven-module:

```
<project>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>shaded.elasticsearch.jackson</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer" />
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
</project>
```

#### 2. And then used that module as a dependency in my main project

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>drivve</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version><!-- be sure to match the version required by elasticsearch-shaded -->
    </dependency>
```

Everything works fine now and is not that hard to managed.
More info on shading es dependencies can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/to-shade-or-not-to-shade).